# Data table row class doesn't update

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

If type column contains data as 'error', how to change row containing that data into 'red background' and 'amber background' when column data contains 'bug'.

For red background class is 'md-bg-red-50', and for amber background class is 'md-bg-amber-50'.

And also I would like to change font color of entire row to red that contains 'error' in 'type' column.

Here is my code:

```
dt_tableTools: function() {
    var $dt_tableTools = $('#dt_tableTools');
    var table1 = $('#dt_tableTools').DataTable({
        "ajax": "results.json",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "assignee" },
            { "data": "type" },
            { "data": "subject" },
            { "data": "priority" },
            { "data": "assigndate" }
        ],
        "createdRow": function(row, data, index){
            if (data[2] == "error") {
                $(row).addClass('md-bg-red-50');
            }
        }
    });
    setInterval(function() {
        table1.ajax.reload(null, false);
    }, 30000);
```

My data Source is:

```
 {
   "data": [
     {
       "id":"29",
       "assignee":"xxxxxxx",
       "type":"bug",
       "subject":"ajax fetch",
       "priority":"1",
       "assigndate":"2018-03-09 12:05:36"
    },
    {
       "id":"28",
       "assignee":"yyyyyyyy",
       "type":"error",
       "subject":"Test 28",
       "priority":"3",
       "assigndate":"2018-03-01 15:46:14"
    },
    {
       "id":"27",
       "assignee":"zzzzzzzzz",
       "type":"error",
       "subject":"Error test",
       "priority":"5",
       "assigndate":"2018-03-01 15:15:42"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Moved actual question before the code sample, split code sample and data source code samples. This makes the question more readable and will improve chances of getting an answer.

Comment: You're doing `data[2] === 'error'`, it should be `data.type === 'error'`.

Comment: Thanks It works like a charm!!!